# ZeroMQ - C++ Publisher and Python Subscriber

Tags: python, c++, zeromq, c++20

I am unable to receive messages sent via ZeroMQ by a C++ publisher with a Python subscriber. Messages sent via Python publisher can be received by a Python subscriber but those sent through a C++ publisher can't.

Here's some more details and simplified code.

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- C++ 20 (cppzmq 4.7.1)
- Python 3.6.9 (pyzmq 22.0.3)

Python Subscriber

```
import zmq
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:98765")
    socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

    while True:
        print(socket.recv())
        time.sleep(1)
```

C++ Publisher (not working)

```
#include <string>
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <unistd.h>

using std::string;

int main() {

    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:98765");

    string pub_msg = "greetings from C++";
    zmq::message_t message_to_send(pub_msg.size());
    memcpy(message_to_send.data(), pub_msg.c_str(), pub_msg.size());
    socket.send(message_to_send, zmq::send_flags::dontwait);
    usleep(10*1000000);

}
```

Python Publisher (working)

```
import zmq
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:98765")

    while True:
        socket.send("greetings from Python")
        time.sleep(1)
```

I want to have the Python subscriber working with C++ publisher. I have tried binding the C++ publisher and connecting Python subscriber but that also doesn't work.

Some direction here would be very helpful.

Thanks
Noman.

Comment: You have a cast there in combination with `memcpy()`, remove that. If it fails to compile, the code is broken. Forcing it to compile won't make it correct, only cause it to fail at runtime instead. Another difference between the two is that one uses the `dontwait` flag and, after queuing data to be sent, it immediately terminates the process.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. Removed the cast to memcpy(message_to_send.data(), pub_msg.c_str(), pub_msg.size()); No compiler error but still unable to receive the message on Python side. Also, added #include <unistd.h> and usleep(10*1000) to give some buffer before terminating. This is only a simplified code; in the actual program, there's more going on and the program doesn't immediately terminate.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out changing

Python

```
socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)  # from context.socket(zmq.SUB)
```

C++

```
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_PUSH);  // from socket(context, ZMQ_PUB)
```

helped fix my problem.

I don't have an explanation for it, but for my use-case, this should do.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the C++ ZMQ_PUB version, its possible the message is being sent before the connect() establishes a connection as its async.

PUB will throw the message away if the connection is not established, PUSH on the other hand will queue.

Try adding a sleep between connect and send